# Sum rows in columns with column names ending with specific character string (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, multiple-columns, rows

I am using the following code, which calculates z scores per subgroup. I would like to add one more column at the end, which sums the z scores, so row-wise sums of all the values in all the columns that end with "_zscore". How could I specifically select those columns?

(Note that my real data have many more columns, so I am looking to specifically select "_zscore" in column names.)

```
 library(dplyr)
 set.seed(12345)
 df1 = data.frame(a=c(rep("a",8), rep("b",5), rep("c",7), rep("d",10)), 
      b=rnorm(30, 6, 2), 
      c=rnorm(30, 12, 3.5), 
      d=rnorm(30, 8, 3)
      )
 df1_z <- df1 %>%
   group_by(a) %>%
   mutate(across(b:d, list(zscore = ~as.numeric(scale(.)))))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use use `select` to select columns that ends with `"zscore"` and use `rowSums` :

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(across(b:d, list(zscore = ~as.numeric(scale(.))))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(total = rowSums(select(., ends_with('zscore'))))

# A tibble: 30 x 8
#   a         b     c     d b_zscore c_zscore d_zscore  total
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 a      7.17 14.8   8.45    0.697   0.101    0.0179  0.816
# 2 a      7.42 19.7   3.97    0.841   1.17    -1.14    0.865
# 3 a      5.78 19.2   9.66   -0.108   1.05     0.332   1.28 
# 4 a      5.09 17.7  12.8    -0.508   0.732    1.14    1.36 
# 5 a      7.21 12.9   6.24    0.721  -0.329   -0.555  -0.163
# 6 a      2.36 13.7   2.50   -2.09   -0.146   -1.52   -3.76 
# 7 a      7.26 10.9  10.7     0.749  -0.774    0.593   0.567
# 8 a      5.45  6.18 12.8    -0.302  -1.80     1.14   -0.965
# 9 b      5.43 18.2   9.55   -0.445   1.12     1.34    2.02 
#10 b      4.16 12.1   4.11   -1.06    0.0776  -1.02   -2.01 
# … with 20 more rows
```

Comment: That's terrific! Thanks so much for your quick reply, Ronak! :)

Comment: Really fast reply :) Ronak, could you, please, explain what is this line about ```mutate(across(b:d, list(zscore = ~as.numeric(scale(.)))))```? Also, I am not a newbie in R, but always wonder what does the dot sign in functions mean? Never met this in practice.

Comment: `across` is used to apply same function to multiple columns (here `b` to `d`). Here we are scaling the values column-wise. `~` and `.` is a formula styled syntax used in `tidyverse` which is an alternative to anonymous function. `.` represents the values of the column.

Answer (score 4):

here is a data.table solution

It basically does the same as the code fom Ronak's answer, but then in the `data.table` syntax.

explanation
`setDT(df1_z)` is used to set `df1_z` to a data.table format
`total := rowSums(.SD)` creates a new column `total`, which had the value of `rowSums` of the `.SD` (a set of selected columns)
`.SDcols = patterns("_zscore$")` defines the selected columns for `.SD`. Here, it are the columns who's name match the regex pattern `_zscore$` (which means: ending with `_zscore`)

```
library( data.table )
setDT(df1_z)[, total := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = patterns("_zscore$")]
```

Comment: Nice one! Thanks! :)